# Unable to locate element in angular js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am new to protractor and i am trying to write a script which will click on the next navigation ">" in the page. I am trying to locate the id from the below code

```
<ul class="pager compact">
<li id="next-page" class="pager-next" ng-show="manager.hasNext" ng- click="next()">
<a href="">Next</a>
</li>
```

and below is the script i am using

```
browser.driver.wait(browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.id('next-page')),6000);
var paginationnext = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('next-page'));
return paginationnext.click();
```

But I see error as mentioned below

```
Unable to locate element:{"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id=next-page"]"}
```

Please help on this front

Comment: is it hidden? you have an 'ng-show' on the li...

Comment: which version of protractor are you using?

Comment: @ Sudharsan Selvaraj I am using protractor version 4.0.3

Comment: @panzhuli i am not sure if it is hidden..could you please eloborate on how to find this? It is actually visible in the UI as on when the page appears..

Comment: you have 'ng-show="manager.hasNext"' on it. Is manager.hasNext true in your test??

Comment: try executeScript like browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].click();', this.paginationnext); if it works then that element is overlapped by some other element.